# SELECT statement for all 3 tables in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I am having trouble writing a `SELECT` query that includes all the 3 tables in a many-to-many relationship. I have the following tables:

```
                                                        Table "public.companies"
     Column     |          Type          |                       Modifiers                        | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
----------------+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id             | integer                | not null default nextval('companies_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 name           | character varying(48)  | not null                                               | extended |              | 
 description    | character varying(512) |                                                        | extended |              | 
 tagline        | character varying(64)  |                                                        | extended |              | 
 featured_image | integer                |                                                        | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "companies_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "company_category_associations" CONSTRAINT "company_category_associations_company_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES companies(id) ON DELETE CASCADE


                            Table "public.company_category_associations"
   Column    |  Type   |                                 Modifiers                                  
-------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 id          | integer | not null default nextval('company_category_associations_id_seq'::regclass)
 company_id  | integer | not null
 category_id | integer | not null
Indexes:
    "company_category_associations_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "company_category_associations_category_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES company_categories(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
    "company_category_associations_company_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES companies(id) ON DELETE CASCADE


                                  Table "public.company_categories"
   Column    |         Type          |                            Modifiers                            
-------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------
 id          | integer               | not null default nextval('company_categories_id_seq'::regclass)
 name        | character varying(32) | not null
 description | character varying(96) | 
Indexes:
    "company_categories_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "company_category_associations" CONSTRAINT "company_category_associations_category_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES company_categories(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

My `companies` table will have around 100k rows and a company can have up to 10 categories associated. Of course I won't be selecting more than 200 companies at a time.

I managed to get the results with the following query:

```
select 
  c.id as companyid, 
  c.name as companyname, 
  cat.id as categoryid, 
  cat.name as categoryname 
from company_categories cat
  left join company_category_associations catassoc on catassoc.category_id = cat.id
  left join companies c on catassoc.company_id = c.id where c.id is not null;
```

This question comes from the fact that I need to present data in JSON format and I would like it to look like this:

```
{
  "companies": [
    {
      "name": "...",
      "description": "...",
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 12,
          "name": "Technology"
        },
        {
          "id": 14,
          "name": "Computers"
        },
      ]
    },
    /* ... */
  ]
}
```

And basically I want to take as much of that data in as few queries as possible.

1. How can I write that `SELECT` query to fit my needs?
2. Is there a problem with the database structure as it is my diagram?

Thank you!

P.S. I am using PostgreSQL 9.6.6

Comment: Why does your association table have an `id` column?

Comment: @melpomene the table was generated from a Laravel migration and I left the `id` column by mistake, but I know it's not ok to have it there

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name please see my edit! Hopefully, it provides enough information this time

Answer (score 1):

You **can** get json out of postgresql directly.

First define composite types (json objects) that you want to output. This is to get names for fields, otherwise they will be named f1,f2,...

```
create type cat as (id integer, name varchar);
create type comp as (id integer, name varchar, categories cat[]);
```

Then select array of comps with nested array of cats as json

```
select to_json(array(
  select (
    c.id,
    c.name,
    array(
      select (cc.id, cc.name)::cat
      from company_categories cc 
      join company_category_associations cca on (cca.category_id=cc.id and cca.company_id=c.id)
    ))::comp
  from companies c
)) as companies
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=531e90933d29f4bf4b235b9e5ef4f755)

Answer (score 0):

You can nest two JSON aggregations to get there.

The first level creates a JSON value for each company with the categories stored as an array:

```
select to_jsonb(c) || jsonb_build_object('categories', jsonb_agg(cc)) comp_json
from companies c
  join company_category_associations cca on cca.company_id = c.id
  join company_categories cc on cc.id = cca.category_id
group by c.id;
```

This returns one row per company. Now we need to aggregate those rows into a single JSON value:

```
select jsonb_build_object('companies', jsonb_agg(comp_json))
from (
  select to_jsonb(c) || jsonb_build_object('{categories}', jsonb_agg(cc)) comp_json
  from companies c
    join company_category_associations cca on cca.company_id = c.id
    join company_categories cc on cc.id = cca.category_id
  group by c.id  
) t;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/TRCR26633